# Understanding Linux audit.logs for SSH - USER_AUTH

Tags: linux, ssh, logs

Let's say I have this entry in my Linux audit.log:

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1357702397.903:2747564): user pid=15121 uid=0
auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="test" 
exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=192.20.11.53 addr=192.20.11.53 terminal=ssh 
es="success"
```

Does this mean that someone has authenticated via SSH using username and password, or with their private key?  Is there a way to tell?

Comment: not from that one line - https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_security/data/sec_audit_aureport.html

Comment: Take a look at the options: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sec-audit_record_types

Comment: From a few basic test... it would appear as if the "USER_AUTH" record type only occurs when a username/password combination is used.  The public key authentication records all seem to start with "USER_ACCT" record types.  However, `/var/log/auth.log` should include the fingerprint of the public key if a key was used... or that the username/password matches.